# How to avoid this sort of paywall when scraping with Python requests?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download content from a website which has a sort of paywall.
You have a number of free articles you can read and then it requires a subscription for you to read more.
However, if you open the link in incognito mode, you can read one more article for each incognito window you open.

So I am trying to download some pages from this site using Python's requests library.
I request the URL and then parse the result using Bs4. However it only works for the first page in the list, the following ones don't have content but have instead the message with "buy a subscription etc.".

How to avoid this?

Comment: I ended up using curl to download the pages and then parsing with Bs4 and it works as intended. Still I have no idea how the site would detect that I am the "same person" when downloading multiple pages via Requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to turn off javascript in the browser, it may work, but not 100%.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).